# Computer restarts itself when I'm playing certain games

Tags: windows-7, reboot

I have been having this problem the past 2 days, and I still am at a loss. I have not changed anything hardware-side in my computer, so I don't think it's got to do with a crappy CPU or RAM or graphics card.I have had this computer, with its current setup, for many months, if not at least a year now, and this has never happened before.

Also, I don't think it's an overheating problem, as it would shut down instead of restart. I guess it wouldn't do any harm to clean it out, though I ran BurnIn Test and it showed no problems, and a steady CPU temeprature of 50-60 degrees celcius.

The drivers for the CPU and graphics card are the latest, and I have defragged the machine.

Lastly, I don't think it is the power supply either, as the computer can stay on for days on end without a problem, and only restarts when I'm playing certain games that have decent graphics, and this has never happened before.

## **EDIT:** Computer details

**OS:**            Windows 7 Home Premium 32bit

**Processor:**     Intel Core i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67GHz 2.67GHz

**RAM:**           4 GB

**Graphics Card:** NVIDIA GeForce GTS 250

**Hard Drive:**    1 TB

Comment: You forgot to give any details on the computer itself. Also overheating can sometimes lead to restarts.

Comment: do you have the restarting on BSOD enabled? Also, is there anything in event viewer at the same time as the reboots? Any recent driver updates?

Comment: Virus information? have you run Spybot S&D?

Comment: What about the GPU temperature? Try [Furmark](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110628/furmark-1-9-1-furmark-1-8-5-download-gpu-stress-test-burn-in-graphics-card-opengl/).

Comment: ^ what he said. pull the video card blow out the dust, and increase the Fan speed to way to high to test the cooling of it. As A Test, so you can reduce the possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I used to have a similar issue on an older machine - in heavy graphics (gaming) it would sometimes reboot. It turned out to be a combination of two things:

Overheating and not enough power - it turned out that as it got hotter the load would increase until it overloaded my PSU which would fail shutting down the motherboard. This would drop the load and the PSU would come straight back on again - letting the PC boot back up.

I would have a look at your PSU as that could definitely cause the problem - simple check: swap the PSU out for another one of higher wattage and see if the problem remains. This is a very quick and simple check.

Comment: Will try that and report back.

Comment: I ultimately took it to service, it was a problem with the graphics card, though I don't know the specifics. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

I updated my motherboard graphics drive which solved my problem. First download [CPUZ](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)  and install it to find your motherboard model number and use this information the find the correct graphics card drives for your system.